# user login problem after upgrading to Django 4.2 from Django 2.0

Tags: python, django

I upgraded my django project from 2.0 to 4.2 and now I am getting the following error on one page where I am using the login() function to log the user in.

Error:

```
The request's session was deleted before the request completed. The user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example.
```

This was working without any problems in django 2.0 and I have been trying to find out the problem for hours but can't find anything related to it. I will attach the code below:

```
def handle_no_permission(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated and not self.test_func() and not self.is_source_email():
            self.raise_exception = True
        if all(x in self.request.GET.keys() for x in ["token", "source"]):
            if self.is_source_email():
                token_from_url = self.request.GET.get("token")
                deficiency_id = self.kwargs.get('deficiency_id')
                try:
                    login_token = ProviderLoginToken.objects.get(key=token_from_url, deficiency_id=deficiency_id)
                    if login_token.active:
                        user = login_token.provider.user
                        user.backend = "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend"
                        print('BEFORE', self.request.user.is_authenticated)
                        login(self.request, user, backend=user.backend)
                        print('AFTER', self.request.user.is_authenticated)
                    else:
                        return render(self.request, "500_invalid_quick_amend_link.html")
                except ProviderLoginToken.DoesNotExist:
                    return render(self.request, "500_invalid_quick_amend_link.html")

        return super().handle_no_permission()
```

The user is able to still login because is_authenticated() returns False before and True after the login() function.

Comment: Could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54687159/9313033

Comment: I have already followed that, but no luck.

Comment: They have migrated to SHA-256 Algo which has longer key and is used for hashing cookies, session and tokens maybe that could have caused the issue: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/3.1/#default-hashing-algorithm-settings try clearing your browser cache and deleting all sessions from your db and then try again.